# Optimization (CodeWars Integers: Recreation One)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I managed to find two algos for [this CodeWars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/integers-recreation-one/train/javascript). Unfortunately, they are not fast enough (> 12000ms).

Any suggestions on how to improve my code?

v1 :

```
const listSquared = (m, n) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = m; i <= n; i++) {
    const divisorsOfi = [];
    for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      if (i % j === 0) {
        divisorsOfi.push(Math.pow(j, 2))
      }
    }
    let sumOfDivisorsOfi = 1;
    if (divisorsOfi.length > 1) {
      sumOfDivisorsOfi = divisorsOfi.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    }
    if (Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(sumOfDivisorsOfi))) {
      result.push([i, sumOfDivisorsOfi]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

v2:

```
const listSquared = (m, n) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = m; i <= n; i++) {
    let sumOfSqrtDivisorsOfi = divisors(i);
    if (Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(sumOfSqrtDivisorsOfi))) {
      result.push([i, sumOfSqrtDivisorsOfi]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const divisors = (n) => [...Array(n + 1).keys()].slice(1)
.reduce((s, a) => s + (!(n % (a)) && Math.pow(a, 2)), 0);
```

Comment: Little clue - you don't need to check all i numbers as divisors of i  here `for (let j = 0; j <= i ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **v1** as a basis and modified it in the following way

```
const listSquared = (m, n) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = m; i <= n; i++) {
    const divisorsOfi = [];
    for (let j = 0; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
      if (i % j === 0) {
        divisorsOfi.push(Math.pow(j, 2));
        if (i/j != j)
          divisorsOfi.push(Math.pow(i/j, 2));

      }
    }
    let sumOfDivisorsOfi = 1;
    if (divisorsOfi.length > 1) {
      sumOfDivisorsOfi = divisorsOfi.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    }
    if (Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(sumOfDivisorsOfi))) {
      result.push([i, sumOfDivisorsOfi]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The idea here is quite simple: if **a** could be divided by **j** then it's also could be divided by **a/j** so we need to check only sqrt(a) first numbers. The only thing you need to be careful is when you count result twice in case **a/j** and **j** is the same number.